# Initialize variable in for loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, initialization

I am wondering if there is any way to define a variable that will be applied " += " operator in for loop, not before that. For example, I can write a code for summation of numbers from 0 to 10 as :

```
sum = 0
for i in range(10): 
    sum += i
```

I just do not want to define the variable "sum" before the loop because it seems so unnecessary. However, I am aware of I have to start that variable otherwise it will give an error or it may be assigned a super unrelated random number which may present its memory address (like in C).

So I want to be able to define its initial value once before for loop. Even thought It seems pretty simple problem, I have made an internet search but I could not find any way to do.

Comment: Why don't just use `sum(range(10))`?

Comment: it was just an example to define the problem easily.

Comment: @Ahmet It seems that it can be solved in anywhere in for loop instead of occupying one more line to just define the variable.

Comment: Number of lines isn't important, execution time/memory concerns are valid but in this case its also irrelevant. Answers given here are bad for code readability, which is a bigger concern, so just use `sum=0`. Also, UBC'den Aydın Alpi tanıyo musun?

Comment: @Ahmet Thanks for clearing up all the things. Yok başkan tanımıyorum ben grad öğrenciyim çoğu Türk'ü tanımıyorum burada.

Comment: @atakanzeybek tamamdır abi kolay gelsin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) and [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) for initialization of sum:

```
for i in range(10): 
    locals().setdefault('sum', 0)
    sum += i
```

Comment: Cool trick, but please don't do this.  No one looking at this will understand why this was done.

Comment: So are you guys saying that if I want to do something like this (that I mentioned), what I did was correct and professional ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce and lambda:

```py
import functools
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, range(10))
```

Check out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce